# Can't select proper item in dropdown list using Selenium Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I would like to ask how I could select item in dropdown list within a suffix (EUR). I tried several ways but it selects wrong item, all time same item even if I change xpath. How to resolve it? I have added photo of HTML code of website, structure of dropdown menu: [image]
My code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import time
import glob
import os, fnmatch
import pandas as pd
import re, os.path
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
#from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
#from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

print("Starting stock script")
p="C:/Users/apskaita3/Finansų analizės ir valdymo sprendimai, UAB/Rokas Toomsalu - Power BI analitika/Integracijos/1_Public comapnies analytics/2. Nasdaq Helsinki/Nasdaq_historical_prices"


stock_list =[


    {"name": "Nordea Bank Ab", "csv_name": "C:/Users/apskaita3/Finansų analizės ir valdymo sprendimai, UAB/Rokas Toomsalu - Power BI analitika/Integracijos/1_Public comapnies analytics/Databasesets/Nasdaq_historical_prices/NDA-FI.csv"}


 ]



for i in stock_list:
    csv_name = i['csv_name']
    print(f"Starting iteration {i}")
    cname = i['name']

#chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#chromeOptions.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9230')

    
#driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\apskaita3\Desktop\gec\geckodriver.exe',service_log_path=os.devnull)
#driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe")

"""
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_argument('headless')
edge_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
edge_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
edge_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
edge_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
"""
#driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe",{"edge_options":"edge_options"})

#driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe",{"edge_options": edge_options})


#driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe", options=edge_options)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/Users/apskaita3/Documents/geckodriver.exe', service_log_path="C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/geckodriver.log")
if cname=="TietoEVRY Oy":



    #driver = webdriver.Edge(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/historicalprices")
    driver.refresh()
    fromDate = driver.find_element_by_id("FromDate")
    fromDate.click()
    fromDate.clear()
    fromDate.send_keys("2006-01-01")
    time.sleep(4)
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("instSearchHistorical")
    inputElement.send_keys(cname)

    #driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    time.sleep(4)
    #s=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ul[3]/li[3]/a/div[3]")
    #s=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'EUR')]")
    #s=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'EUR')]")
    foo= "EUR"
    #s = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='" + foo + "']")
    #s=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='My Button']")
    #s=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[normalize-space()='EUR']]")
    s=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='EUR']")
    print("s",s)
    #s=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[matches(.,'EUR', 'i')]")
    #element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Nordea Bank Abp (EUR)']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[3].click();", s)
    #.click()
    #inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.acSearchResult-fnm').click()


    new_csv1 = pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';')
    if ('sep='  in new_csv1.columns.tolist()):
        new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';',skiprows=1)
    else:
        new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=',')

    new_df1 = pd.concat([old_csv1, new_csv1]).reset_index(drop=True)
    #old_csv1=new_csv1
    new_df1.columns = old_csv1.columns
    new_df1['Trades']=new_df1['Trades'].replace(" ", "")
    new_df1=new_df1.sort_values('Date', ascending = False).drop_duplicates()
    if 'Unnamed: 11' in new_df1.columns.tolist():
        del new_df1['Unnamed: 11']
    else:
        pass
    new_df1.to_csv(csv_name,index = False)
    print(new_df1.duplicated())


    os.chdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads")
    for e in os.listdir():
      if "-2006-01-01" in e:
        os.remove(e)
      else:
        pass
            

    
    filenames.clear()
    time.sleep(3)       

    driver.find_element_by_id("showAdjusted").click()

                    
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_id("exportExcel").click()
    print(5)
    time.sleep(8)
    
    driver.close()

    time.sleep(3)
    print(5)

    #path = "C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/"
    accepted_extensions = ["csv"]
    filenames = [fn for fn in os.listdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/") if fn.split(".")[-1] in accepted_extensions]
    #filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)
    #print(filenames)
    #filenames=re.search("2006",filenames) 
    #print(filenames)
     
    filenames = [s for s in filenames if "-2006-01-01" in s]

    print(os.listdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/"))
    
    print(filenames)
    a1=filenames[0]

    try:
        old_csv1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/{a1}',sep=';',skiprows=1)
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
      #old_csv14 = pd.DataFrame()
        old_csv1  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Opening price','High price','Low price','Closing price', 'Average price','Total volume','Turnover','Trades'])

    new_csv1 = pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';')
    if ('sep='  in new_csv1.columns.tolist()):
        new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';',skiprows=1)
    else:
        new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=',')

    new_df1 = pd.concat([old_csv1, new_csv1]).reset_index(drop=True)
    #old_csv1=new_csv1
    new_df1.columns = old_csv1.columns
    new_df1['Trades']=new_df1['Trades'].replace(" ", "")
    new_df1=new_df1.sort_values('Date', ascending = False).drop_duplicates()
    if 'Unnamed: 11' in new_df1.columns.tolist():
        del new_df1['Unnamed: 11']
    else:
        pass
    new_df1.to_csv(csv_name,index = False)
    print(new_df1.duplicated())


    os.chdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads")
    for e in os.listdir():
      if "-2006-01-01" in e:
        os.remove(e)
      else:
        pass
            

    
    filenames.clear()
    time.sleep(3)
else:
    #driver = webdriver.Edge(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/historicalprices")
    driver.refresh()
    fromDate = driver.find_element_by_id("FromDate")
    fromDate.click()
    fromDate.clear()
    fromDate.send_keys("2006-01-01")
    time.sleep(4)
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("instSearchHistorical")
    inputElement.send_keys(cname)

    #driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    time.sleep(4)
    s=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ul[2]/li[2]/a/div[1]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", s)
    #.click()
    #inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.acSearchResult-fnm').click()

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_element_by_id("showAdjusted").click()

                    
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_id("exportExcel").click()
    print(5)
    time.sleep(8)
    
    driver.close()

    time.sleep(3)
    print(5)

    #path = "C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/"
    accepted_extensions = ["csv"]
    filenames = [fn for fn in os.listdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/") if fn.split(".")[-1] in accepted_extensions]
    #filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)
    #print(filenames)
    #filenames=re.search("2006",filenames) 
    #print(filenames)
     
    filenames = [s for s in filenames if "-2006-01-01" in s]

    print(os.listdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/"))
    
    print(filenames)
    a1=filenames[0]

    try:
        old_csv1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/{a1}',sep=';',skiprows=1)
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
      #old_csv14 = pd.DataFrame()
        old_csv1  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Opening price','High price','Low price','Closing price', 'Average price','Total volume','Turnover','Trades'])

    new_csv1 = pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';')
    if ('sep='  in new_csv1.columns.tolist()):
        new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';',skiprows=1)
    else:
        new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=',')

    new_df1 = pd.concat([old_csv1, new_csv1]).reset_index(drop=True)
    #old_csv1=new_csv1
    new_df1.columns = old_csv1.columns
    new_df1['Trades']=new_df1['Trades'].replace(" ", "")
    new_df1=new_df1.sort_values('Date', ascending = False).drop_duplicates()
    if 'Unnamed: 11' in new_df1.columns.tolist():
        del new_df1['Unnamed: 11']
    else:
        pass
    new_df1.to_csv(csv_name,index = False)
    print(new_df1.duplicated())


    os.chdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads")
    for e in os.listdir():
      if "-2006-01-01" in e:
        os.remove(e)
      else:
        pass
            

    
    filenames.clear()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Website https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/historicalprices.
Dropdown list:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to show the HTML of the list elements? That would help others to help you.

Comment: @KatePaulk please check it, I have added it already.

Comment: Actually the image you added shows the parent `<ul>` expanded, but the child `<li>` elements are not expanded. It's that information that might help.